# Excel 2016: How to select function from "suggested" dropdown list *by keyboard*?

Tags: function, input, keyboard, selection, excel-2016

A minor usability annoyance (or possibly ignorance):

In order to use a pre-defined function (such as SUM()) in Excel 2016 (under Win10), I type "=" (without quotation marks) into the respective cell, then the first letters of the function name, say "XY".

Thereupon, Excel opens a dropdown "suggestion" list of all functions starting with "XY".

I can select one of those by *double-clicking*, the full function name will be filled in, and the arguments etc. can be added.

I can also use the *arrow keys* to select an entry from the dropdown, but when I then hit ENTER to actually use it, the cell will display a "#NAME?" error -- correctly so, because it still only contains the string I entered ("=XY") but the rest of the function name from the list has *not* been inserted automatically.

How can I select and then use a function from the suggestion list **by keyboard only**?

Other than the obvious ENTER I have tried ctrl-ENTER, shift-ENTER, alt-ENTER, TAB, all to no avail. Web search found no results, perhaps because no one requires (or even knows about) "keyboard only" any more? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have highlighted the function, use the tab key